# jquery fadein(), a little help please

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have an extremely simple script (as I am a JQ noob)
Its so simple I'm not even going to make a fiddle but will post the code below:

```
        var tip;
                    var orig;
                    var switched = 0;



                    $('.output').hover(function () {

                         tip =  $(this).attr('title');
                         orig = $(this).text();


                        if(tip != orig)
                        {
                        $(this).text(tip).fadeIn(2000);
                        switched = 1;
                        }

                    }, function () {

                        if(switched == 1)
                        {
                        $(this).text(orig).fadeIn();
                        }

                    });
```

It works as expected, as I mouseover a `span` with the class "output" it switches the value with the `title` of that `span`, but my problem is it does not fadein the text. How do I get it to fade in the title?  (both on mouse in and mouse out)

HTML is like this:

```
<span class="output italic" title="Computer_Science.jpg">Computer_Science.j...</span>
```

Comment: if the content is already displayed then there won't be any fading effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `fadeIn` after a `fadeOut` has completed. That is because, if it is already visible then another `fadeIn` will not have any effect on it. So, you have to first `fadeOut` and then once that is complete, call the `fadeIn`.

Both, `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` have a callback as a parameter which gets called once the effect is complete. Wrap your code as an anonymous callback as that parameter to the `fadeOut`.

***Snippet***:

```js
var tip;
var orig;
var switched = 0;

$('.output').hover(function () {
    tip = $(this).attr('title');
    orig = $(this).text();
    if (tip != orig) {
        $(this).fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).text(tip).fadeIn();
            switched = 1;
        });
    }
},
    function () {
        if (switched == 1) {
            $(this).fadeOut(function () {
                $(this).text(orig).fadeIn();
                switched = 0;
            });
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span title="Title" class="output">Hello</span>
```

Comment: Can't accept your answer for a few more mins, will do so when the clock runs out